# Bulk-change Post slugs which have a suffix

Tags: slug

I've got a bunch of slugs that look something like this:

```
pageA-2
pageB-2
```

etc.

Fwiw, I think I did an import, then moved those to Trash, then did another import. Because I had Pages with an existing slug, the new Pages were given a "-2" suffix.

The question, however, is can I automatically rename all of these slugs and delete these suffixes? Either in pure SQL or via a Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would backup and restore the site on a local development environment. Then you can try use this tool on your local site: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
Make sure that when you rename you are giving them something unique otherwise you may get in trouble.